# Pre-load large file into python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a multi-threaded web (json) server -- for each incoming request a thread is spawned which in turn spawns several "worker" threads itself. Some workers need to load a large dictionary:

```
dictfile = 'a_very_large_english_dictionary.pickle'
self.english_dict = pickle.load(open(dictfile, 'rb'))
```

This is one large object that every other worker needs to access. I want it to be loaded only once. I could load it on the server level and then pass it around as an argument, but that would be ugly. What is the best mechanism for this?

Comment: You could load it into a global variable.

Comment: @alden Thank you, it is even easier than I expected. Previous iteration of code used multiprocessing so I could not use globals.